# node.js + express.js: session handling with mongodb/mongoose

Tags: session, mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

Right now i'm storing my session data in the "memory store" which comes bundled with connect(express). But I want/have to change this for production.

The application is using mongodb and I installed mongoose to handle all db-communications.

e.g. Connect to the DB after initializing my app:

```
var mongo = require('mongoose');
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDb');
mongo.connection.on('open', function () {
  app.listen(3000);
}
```

I found the connect-mongodb module, but I don't know how to implement it using mongoose, or if it's actually possible?
I need to add something like this:

```
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');
// ...
app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'topsecret',
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  store: new mongoStore({ db: 'myDb' })
}));
```

or do I have to define my db connection a second time using the mongodb-module directly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

in the end i'm using a bit of every answer that was given before:

- i switched from connect-mongodb to connect-mongo module
- i'm using a general conf object to store my configuration data
- there are two db connections because it's easier to handle for me (maybe changed later on, if/when a new version of mongoose/express comes out)

requirements:

```
var express = require('express'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express),
    mongo = require('mongoose');
```

conf object:

```
var conf = {
  db: {
    db: 'myDb',
    host: '192.168.1.111',
    port: 6646,  // optional, default: 27017
    username: 'admin', // optional
    password: 'secret', // optional
    collection: 'mySessions' // optional, default: sessions
  },
  secret: '076ee61d63aa10a125ea872411e433b9'
};
```

then i can configure it like this:

```
app.configure(function(){
  // ...
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore(conf.db)
  }));
  // important that this comes after session management
  app.use(app.router);
  // ...
});
```

and finally connect to mongodb a second time using mongoose:

```
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://';
dbUrl += conf.db.username + ':' + conf.db.password + '@';
dbUrl += conf.db.host + ':' + conf.db.port;
dbUrl += '/' + conf.db.db;
mongo.connect(dbUrl);
mongo.connection.on('open', function () {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: Good work!  Only addition I have that was compounding my troubles is to make sure that your "app.use(app.router);" is placed after the "app.use(express.session...".

Comment: For anyone trying to get this working recently: it seems that as of v0.1.9, you'll need to set express as a varilable (`var express = require('express')`) and then pass that to connect-mongo (`var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express)`). This works because express exposes all of the underlying parts of connect, and connect-mongo is actually a function that takes the connect object as an argument.

Comment: In order to avoid EADDRINUSE errors I had to remove the "app.listen(3000)" line from the bottom section of code that you had, because I was already doing my .listen somewhere else. That part only needs to be done once and is for starting the actual express webserver itself -- not relevant per se to the mongodb connection. Just a note!

Comment: Okay, I reached till here, but now how do I interact with the session? set and get values..

Comment: @Hadesara There is excellent documentation on expressjs and sessions here: 

http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/express-js-sessions-a-detailed-tutorial

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to understand `express-session` myself and I've run into an issue when ti comes to storing sessions in `mongoDB` - Do you think you could take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413051/express-js-multiple-temp-sessions-for-same-domain-in-mongodb ? Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Please include

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

directly before

```
app.use(express.session({
```

Otherwise throws error as below,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined

Comment: That saves lives. The internet is wrong on this - there wasn't a single example from the top of the results even suggesting about this.

Comment: thanks for the hint but next time, just edit my answer and add the missing line so that others won't have to read another answer ...

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you could do this to setup `connect-mongodb` assuming your mongoose connection code above is run earlier:

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'topsecret',
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  store: new mongoStore({ db: mongoose.connections[0].db })
}));
```

Comment: i'm using the express.session() in app.configure() before i connect to the DB. i think, i'll define a config object which contains all DB info and try to use connect-mongo (instead of connect-mongodb) - implementation looks easier than connect-mongodb

Comment: the example in the github page doesn't tell how to use with mongoose. this example helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

So `connect-mongodb` does not use Mongoose, it uses the `node-mongodb-native` driver (*i.e.:* `npm install mongodb`). Mongoose also depends on this driver, so it should be present.

Looking at [the code directly](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js), you have to provide your DB connection information as a `MongoStore` object:

```
store: new mongoStore({ host: 'session_server', port: 27017, db: 'seesion', collection: 'sessions' })
```

Typically for this, you'll want to have some "config" object or variable that can be dynamically loaded (dev vs test vs prod). Then you pull the host/port/db/auth off of that config object.

Comment: you link to connect-mongo, i used connect-mongodb in the example. but they're almost identical, so i will check this out.

Answer (score 3):

For express 4x:

```
var express = require('express'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    mongo = require('mongoose');

var conf = {
  db: {
    db: 'myDb',
    host: '192.168.1.111',
    port: 6646,  // optional, default: 27017
    username: 'admin', // optional
    password: 'secret', // optional
    collection: 'mySessions' // optional, default: sessions
  },
  secret: '076ee61d63aa10a125ea872411e433b9'
};

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore(conf.db)
  }));
});

var dbUrl = 'mongodb://';
dbUrl += conf.db.username + ':' + conf.db.password + '@';
dbUrl += conf.db.host + ':' + conf.db.port;
dbUrl += '/' + conf.db.db;
mongo.connect(dbUrl);
mongo.connection.on('open', function () {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

`session` has been moved to it's own module, so you need to `require` it and use `session` when configuring the `MongoStore`.

Comment: In line 3, what exactly it means by (session) after require statement. Is it like  (session) is passed to mongoStore

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in an object of connection details (host, username, password, etc.).

You can also pass in a connection url like mongodb://user:pass@host.com/db_name.

Both those methods will automatically start a new connection, regardless of whether or not you already have or will start a mongoose connection.

In the latest code, you can pass in a handle to an existing connection, an instance of `mongodb.Db`. With mongoose, this would be `mongoose.connection.db`. However, this code isn't in an actual release, and when I tried it, it didn't work. Probably not ready to be used yet (or untested).

I'm sure if you wait for the next release, you'll be able to pass in an existing mongoose connection. In the mean time you'll just need to accept having two connections, one from mongoose and one from connect-mongodb.

I got the connection info from https://github.com/tedeh/connect-mongodb and I got the handle information from viewing the source ([relevant commit](https://github.com/tedeh/connect-mongodb/commit/9caca15ea89096cad6813b82dcfad3f037c8edc4)).

Answer (score 0):

I just stumble across [mongoose-session](https://github.com/TheRealCharDev/mongoose-session)

Very lightweight and worked seamlessly for me. From github...

**Installation**

```
npm install mongoose-session
```

**Use**

```
var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

var app = express();

app.use(require('express-session')({
    key: 'session',
    secret: 'SUPER SECRET SECRET',
    store: require('mongoose-session')(mongoose)
}));
```

Comment: From repo `mongoose-session`, **INACTIVE. Use connect-mongo instead. It's better anyways.**