# Where should i store current user in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

As with almost any web application, I need a way to reference the current user in my node.js app.

I have the login/session system working, but I noticed today that when I login to my app in one browser, and view it in another, I can see the same data that I see in the first browser.

I am currently storing the information about the current user in a global app.current_user object, but I realize now that this is shared across all requests/sessions because node.js is single-threaded - and therefore, is a bad idea.

What would be the correct way to store the reference to the current user? The current user is not just a hash of user data, but a Mongoose model, so I guess storing in a cookie would not be a good idea?

BTW - I also store the user's settings and a few more things that I do not want to fetch again each time I do something with the user and their settings (which can happen quite a few times during a single request). I guess you could say I'm caching the current user in memory.

Comment: I use passport.js for authentication and all the user information is stored in req.user. I created my own mongoose model for my user as well.

Comment: @StanCromlish - it just dawned to me that req is scoped to the current request (ie it is not global), so this would work. However, I'm not sure if I can pass the req object around in my app (using Locomotivejs  framework here)

Comment: I don't know either about Locomotivejs.  I pass the req object around in my Node.js with Express and EJS Views.  If you can route with req, res with Locomotive, you should be able to do just fine.

Comment: I wonder how I could pass the req object to Mongoose middleware and schema defaults? Basically, I need to set some stuff in the middleware based on the 'current' user, and also, I need to load some defaults from the 'current' settings in the mongoose schema defaults.

Comment: @ragulka if you have found the right solution, please do share. I think it is pretty common requirement. for example, update DB in service with updated/created by user ID from current user context. I don't like the idea of passing around req object in my service modules.

Comment: @SamSerious I have posted my own current solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the correct place to store information about the current user at the moment is in the request object.

If you do not like the idea of passing the request object to mongoose or other modules, then you need to make any changes in your router/controller/middleware. For example, I can set the `lastModifiedBy` user ID for the `Post` model in my `posts_controller` `update()` action.

You can also try using the fairly new `domain` feature to store current user data, but when working with Mongoose, it doesn't help yet, because Mongoose does not support domains yet: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/1337

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes here, like me, looking for passing implicit context and is using express.

I ended up using express-http-context for this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-context)

From the docs:

```js
var express = require('express');
var httpContext = require('express-http-context');
 
var app = express();
// Use any third party middleware that does not need access to the context here, e.g. 
// app.use(some3rdParty.middleware);
app.use(httpContext.middleware);
// all code from here on has access to the same context for each request
```

Get the user or whatever data you want to keep:

```js
// Example authorization middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    userService.getUser(req.get('Authorization'), (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            httpContext.set('user', result.user)
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Somewhere else where you need the value:

```js
var httpContext = require('express-http-context');
 
// Somewhere deep in the Todo Service
function createTodoItem(title, content, callback) {
    var user = httpContext.get('user');
    db.insert({ title, content, userId: user.id }, callback);
}
```

Comment: I had tried your solution but I couldn't get it working. Since I'm using VS2013 I had to use an older version of Node.js so it doesn't recognize arrow functions so I did ```app.use(function (req, res, next)
{
    userService.getUser(req.get('Authorization'), function(err, result)
    {
        if (err) {
        next(err);
        } 
        else {
        httpContext.set('user', result.user)
        next();
    }
    });
});``` and I had got an error about userService not recognized.

Comment: Hi userService here is just the service I used to load the user and was available in the scope for me. You will have to replace the `userService.getUser` bit with your code to load  the data you want to store in the context.

Answer (score 0):

In express you can use session

```
//To set up session 
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret pass', store: sessionStore})); 
//To use it
req.session = {user:name , model:mongo_model};
console.log(req.session.user);
```

Examples

1. See a simple example [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/session/index.js)
2. See how to use mongostore for session data in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819911/node-js-express-js-session-handling-with-mongodb-mongoose)

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvote here? I'd like to know why this isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have sessions implemented, place before all routes, a middleware that finds the currently logged in user and store it in res.locals. This make the user data available for all routes which you can access anywhere in your app like below.

The *else if* section is for remember me functionality. This functionality stores the remember token and userid in the cookie object/signedCookie object depending on whether there was a secret or not.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (req.session.userId){
        User.findById(req.session.userId, function(err, u){
        res.locals.currentUser = res.locals.currentUser || u
        next()
        })
    }else if (req.signedCookies.userID){ // if the user previously checked remember me
        User.findById(req.signedCookies.userID, function(err, u){
            if (u && u.authenticated(req.signedCookies.rToken, u.rememberDigest)){
                req.session.userId = u._id // re logs in user by resetting session  
                res.locals.currentUser = res.locals.currentUser || u
                next()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Inspired by Micheal Hartl's Rails book